# How to Disambiguate Command Line and Variable Arguments in Lua?

Tags: lua, arguments, luajit

Specifically, Luajit.
I am writing a script as a learning exercise and am attempting to use variable arguments. However, doing so just prints the *command line* arguments. I double-checked the documentation and, indeed, both applications use the `arg` variable.

How do I specify when I want to use one instead of the other?

```
function init(...)
    for k,v in pairs(arg) do print(k,v) end
    -- Function body.
end
```

Output,

```
0   /.../lua_script.lua
-1  luajit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LuaJIT, stemming from Lua 5.1, uses the newer vararg syntax, wherein you manually capture the varargs into a table:

```
function init (...)
  local args = { ... }
  for k, v in pairs(args) do print(k, v) end
end
```

The special `arg` variable, in LuaJIT, is only used for command-line arguments.

See the third item in the [LuaJIT FAQ](http://luajit.org/faq.html).

Comment: Ooh, okay! Thanks! So Lua 5.3 has a new way of doing it?

Comment: @LemmaPrism Err, actually, upon closer examination it looks like this way *is* the newer (5.1+) way to do it and that `arg` was the old way. I think...very confusing since the online PIL is outdated...

Comment: Oh, huh! Well that's kinda hilarious. Good to know that the PIL is out date...
So, both Luajit and Lua5.1+ do CMD args via `arg` and varargs via `{...}`.